# In windows convert jpg to bit array, pass to raspberry pi, convert bit array back to jpg using raspberry pi os and python

Tags: python, windows, image, sockets, raspberry-pi

My purpose is to grab an image (any format), convert it to a byte array, process the byte array, then pass it to my Raspberry PI and then process the resyltant byte array using Python (or OpenCV) to render the original file in as near to the original as is possible. Is this something that can be done?

For instance, I take a jpeg file, convert it to a byte array, use an encryption on this byte array, then pass it through a socket connection (binary TCP) and then decrypt this byte array on the Pi and render the jpeg in as close to the orinal as possible. How might I do this?

Comment: This is all very vague... my purpose is to grab an image *"where from... camera? disk? video"*... convert it to a byte array... *"why?"*... encrypt it... *"why, who's looking?"*... pass it to a Raspberry Pi... *"what for?"* and make it as close to the original as possible... *"why? Surely encryption should be lossless"*? Please try to improve your question so folks can assist you more readily. Thank you.

Comment: I've done something similar passing images from the raspberry pi camera to a Windows app in BMP format. This was using the PIL library to load the image and save it to an IOBytes object. This link may give more information: [send pil image through socket without saving python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366695/send-pil-image-through-socket-without-saving-python)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.